# Which of these MySQL database designs (attached) is best for mostly read high performance?

Tags: mysql, database, performance, database-design

I am a data base admin and developer in MySQL. I have been a couple of years working with MySQL. I recently adquire and study O'Reilly High Performance MySQL 2nd Edition to improve my skills on MySQL advanced features, high performance and scalability, because I have often been frustated by the lack of advance knowledge of MySQL I had (and in a big part, I still have).

Currently, I am working on a ambicious web project. In this project, we will have quite content and users from the begining. I am the designer of the data base and this data base must be very fast (some inserts but mostly and more important READS).

I want here to discuss about these **requirements**:

- There will be **several kind of items**
- The items have some fields and relations in **common**
- The items also have some fields and relations **special** that make them differents each other
- Those items will have to be **listed all** together ordered or filtered by common fields or relations
- The items will have to be also **listed only by type** (for examble item_specialA)

I have some basic design doubts, and I would like you to help me decide and learn which design aproach would be better for a high performance MySQL data base.

**Classical aproach**

The following diagram shows the clasical aproach which is the first you may think about with the mind thinking in database: **[Database diagram](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/25719335/clasicDiagram.png)**

**Centralized aproach**

But maybe we can improve it with some or pseudo object oriented paradigm centralicing the common items and the relations on one common item table. It would also be useful for listing all kind of items: **[Database diagram](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/25719335/centralizedDiagram.png)**

---

- **Advantages and disadvantages of each one?**
- **Which aproach would you choose or which changes would you apply seeing the requirements seen before?**

Thanks all in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have are two distinct data mapping strategies. That you called "classical" is "one table per concrete class" in other sources, and that you called "centralized" is "one table per class" ([Mapping Objects to Relational Databases: O/R Mapping In Detail](http://www.agiledata.org/essays/mappingObjects.html#ComparingTheStrategies)). They both have their advantages and disadvantages (follow the link above). The queries in the first strategy will be faster (you will need to join only 2 tables vs 3 in the second strategy).

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should explore classic supertype/subtype pattern. Here are **[some examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:196713%20subtype)** from the SO.

Comment: It has helped me, but i would like to get a little more depper in the examples I have posted above.

Comment: @Emilio, it is hard to read your model, everything is called item or item_special. Is it that you do not know what items are (could be) or ...?

Comment: It is an example. Item_specialA, B or C, are the childs of item. I know already which are they, but it would get more complicate to read the models.

You can also read the notes in the diagram to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking mostly for speed, consider selective use of MyISAM tables, use a centralized "object" table, and just one additional table with correct indexes on this form:

```
object_type | object_id | property_name | property_value
user        | 1         | photos        | true
city        | 2         | photos        | true
user        | 5         | single        | true
city        | 2         | metro         | true
city        | 3         | population    | 135000
```

and so on... lookups on primary keys or indexed keys (object_type, object_id, property_name) for example will be blazing fast. Also, you reduce the need to end with 457 tables as new properties appear.

It isn't exactly a well-designed nor perfectly-normalized database and, if you are looking for a long-term big site, you should consider caching, or at least using a denormalized paradigm, denormalized mysql tables like this one, redis, or maybe MongoDB.

Comment: Why MyISAM and not InnoDB? InnoDB scales better and has faster primary key lookups.

Comment: "selective use" , user noted as a requirement (some inserts but mostly and more important READS), almost any tip on the interwebs will lead us to selective use of MyISAM for high read/write rates. For reads, MyISAM have been historically faster. For writes, InnoDB is transactional, MyISAM doesn't worry about atomic writes, so it will be also quicker.

Comment: Sorry, properly configured MySQL instance on non-commodity hardware will yield better results with InnoDB. InnoDB has different method of storing data based on primary key so primary key lookups **will** be faster. Try to google HandlerSocket and check why. On the other hand - yes, MyISAM is faster when it comes to writes, but not when it comes to reads (not talking about small amount of data, it performs better with smaller amount).

Comment: Also, if you can trade disk for speed, you could try a simple "ALTER TABLE tblname ROW_FORMAT=FIXED;" in your tables, it should give you an aditional performance boost of around 15-20% in some cases. Take a look at DYNAMIC (default) versus FIXED size tables.

Comment: Sure you are right when we enter the world of "big data", i have tried Percona patches and so on... but i think the case escenario of the original post (as i know the project) will never reach more than, maybe, 100k unique objects, as it is a "students travels" network and i really think that's the "top" records they could have, so in fact, for me that's a fair small amount of data and i could consider any InnoDB or MyISAM, just pointed MyISAM as for the "overall" spedd. Imho, just a good design, even with no denormalization, should suffice for this use case.

Comment: Even with small amount of data, you can fit InnoDB dataset in the buffer pool. MyISAM will use OS cache. It's probably totally unnecessary to mention this for a project with low amount of data, however I still stand to my claim that InnoDB **is** faster in reads when configured properly and paired with right hardware.

Comment: Thanks for your points of view. It is very useful to listen to all the aproaches!, advantages and disadvantages :-)